# how to use mysql like operator inside if else condition in php

Tags: php, mysql

I written mysql like operator inside if else condition in php. But am not getting output, Can anyone tell me how to use it. I am giving my code below

```
   if ($role == "admin")
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM registration";
}
elseif($role == 'M%')
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM registration where reporting_manager='$role' OR role='$role'";
}
else
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM registration WHERE role='$role'";
}
```

but its not taking the second condition, directly going to last. What the mistake i had done in this code, or how to write the like operator in if else condition.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value of `$role`

Comment: that is taken from text field(form). It's taking correctly

Comment: He wasnn't ask from what yoo have this value but what **contains** this value. Try to read more carefully what people ask for.

Comment: Try using else if($role == 'M%') instead of elseif($role == 'M%') , not sure if it makes a difference but I feel like there should be a space inbetween there.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing mysql with php.
use the following PHP:

```
elseif(strtoupper($role[0]) === 'M')
```

Comment: $role is not an array, so can we use like this?

Comment: yup, [0] takes the first character from string $role

Answer (score 0):

Try this one query;)

```
$sql = "SELECT *
      FROM registration
      WHERE ('$role' = 'admin')
      OR ('$role' = 'M%' AND (reporting_manager='$role' OR role='$role')) 
      OR (role='$role')";
```